# Overriding the DefaultValue of a parent's properties

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, controls, system.componentmodel

I'm inheriting a Control, with the goal of overriding the value of the [DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) attribute of some properties. However, to do this I need to add some boilerplate to create "proxies" to the parent class's properties, like this:

```
<DefaultValue("new_default_value")> _
Public Overloads Property SomeProperty As String
    Get
        Return MyBase.SomeProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        MyBase.SomeProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
```

My question is, is there any better way of overriding the value of the DefaultValue attribute without using this? As long as its usable/visible from the Visual Studio Form Designer.

Comment: This makes little sense.  You want the default value to be editable in the Properties window??

Comment: @HansPassant No, I want to change the default value of properties in a base class (which I'm already doing using the above method, but I'm trying to find a better way of achieving that). These "default values" refer to the values that the control has in its properties when one creates a new control in a form.